# adding too many JS functions into one - NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Using JS for an auto complete in the text box.  All working fine, however i want to add another 2 different text boxes with auto complete to the page.  Not working and not giving any specific erros, prob a comma missing somehwere or something to that effect if anyone could have a look over the code and correct me that would be great. thanks

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProductRecord_Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProductRecord_Name, new { @class = "form-control uppercase" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductRecord_Id)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ProductRecord_Id)
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                    var products = [
                                        @{
                                        bool addComma1 = false;
                                        foreach (StockControl.Models.ProductRecord product in Model.ProductRecords)
                                        {
                                            if (addComma1)
                                            {
                                                <text> @Html.Raw(",") </text>
                                            }

                                                <text> @Html.Raw(string.Format("{{ value: \"{0}\", label: \"{1}\" }}", product.Id, product.Name)) </text>

                                            addComma1 = true;
                                        }
                                        }               
                                    ];

                $("#ProductRecord_Name").autocomplete({ 
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: customers,
                    focus: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#ProductRecord_Name").val(ui.item.label); 
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label).change();
                        $("#ProductRecord_Id").val(ui.item.value);
                        return false;
                    }
                });

</script>
```

THIS ALL WORKS FINE PROBLEM IS WHEN I TRY TO ADD MORE CODE TO THE JS...NOT SURE OF THE ACTUAL LAYOUT, DOES THE ARRAYS GO AFTER EACH OTHER OR SEPARATE $(document).ready(function () FUNCTIONS:
(DOES THIS LOOK CORRECT...CANT SEE WHAT I AM MISSIG...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                    var products = [
                                        @{
                                        bool addComma1 = false;
                                        foreach (ACCS.StockControl.Models.ProductRecord product in Model.ProductRecords)
                                        {
                                            if (addComma1)
                                            {
                                                <text> @Html.Raw(",") </text>
                                            }

                                                <text> @Html.Raw(string.Format("{{ value: \"{0}\", label: \"{1}\" }}", product.Id, product.Name)) </text>

                                            addComma1 = true;
                                        }
                                        }               
                                    ];

                  var unitsOfSale = [
                                        @{
                                        bool addComma2 = false;
                                        foreach (ACCS.StockControl.Models.UnitOfSaleRecord unit in Model.UnitOfSaleRecords)
                                        {
                                            if (addComma2)
                                            {
                                                <text> @Html.Raw(",") </text>
                                            }

                                                <text> @Html.Raw(string.Format("{{ value: \"{0}\", label: \"{1}\" }}", unit.Id, unit.Name)) </text>

                                            addComma2 = true;
                                        }
                                        }               
                                    ];

                  var caseSizes = [
                                        @{
                                        bool addComma3 = false;
                                        foreach (ACCS.StockControl.Models.CaseSizeRecord caseSize in Model.CaseSizeRecords)
                                        {
                                            if (addComma3)
                                            {
                                                <text> @Html.Raw(",") </text>
                                            }

                                                <text> @Html.Raw(string.Format("{{ value: \"{0}\", label: \"{1}\" }}", caseSize.Id, caseSize.Description)) </text>

                                            addComma3 = true;
                                        }
                                        }               
                                    ];

                $("#ProductRecord_Name").autocomplete({ 
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: products,
                    focus: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#ProductRecord_Name").val(ui.item.label); 
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label).change();
                        $("#ProductRecord_Id").val(ui.item.value);
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                  $("#UnitOfSaleRecord_Name").autocomplete({ 
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: unitsOfSale,
                    focus: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#UnitOfSaleRecord_Name").val(ui.item.label); 
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label).change();
                        $("#UnitOfSaleRecord_Id").val(ui.item.value);
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                  $("#CaseSize_Name").autocomplete({ 
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: caseSizes,
                    focus: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#CaseSize_Name").val(ui.item.label); 
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label).change();
                        $("#CaseSize_Id").val(ui.item.value);
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            </script>
```

Comment: not sure I see where the call to `$(document).ready(` is closed

Answer (score 1):

Have you used firebug (or other Web dev. tool) do debug that code step by step? Check the contents of those arrays.

Are you showing all the relevant code?

You're assigning `customers` as a source to `$("#ProductRecord_Name")` but I only see a `var products`.

Comment: ahh yes changes the customers to suit and didnt change it in the other part il try now

Comment: iv never used fire bug before, only really new to JS as well...il download it now thanks

Comment: Ok. Firebug's console should show you any synthax errors. On the "scripts" tab you can place breakpoints on your JS code.

Comment: If you figured out a solution, you should post it as an answer.